# Some questions about random numbers

Tags: random, probability-or-statistics

How can I get non-repeating random numbers from Mathematica 8?

How can I know which distribution the numbers I get are?

Can I choose the distribution I want together with the non-repeating random numbers?

How to write the expressions or formulas of permutation and combination?

Are these numbers real random numbers, not pseudo-random numbers?

Comment: Sorry, the "random" numbers in *Mathematica* are always pseudorandom. If you're fine with that, look into `RandomReal[]` and `RandomVariate[]`.

Comment: Most of your questions (for Mathematica) can be answered if you take a look into the help. 1. Use `RandomReal[]` or `RandomInteger[]` or `RandomComplex[]` without `SeedRandom[]`. 2. The numbers of `RandomReal[]` etc. are uniformly distributed over the range you have chosen. 3. Should be possible, take a look at `RandomVariate[]`. 4. That is something I do not know well, but I think the documentation can help again. 5. They are pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: For 4: permutations are represented by `FactorialPower[]`; combinations are represented by `Binomial[]`.

Comment: Given the finite number of numbers that can be given with any given fixed amount of precision it is impossible to get an infinite amount *non-repeating* random numbers. For instance, RandomInteger[9], can only generate 10 different numbers and if we have drawn them all the party is over. So, could you be a bit more explicit about this *non-repeating* requirement of yours?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: For a random drawing without repetition with the number of drawings equal the number of available items, I'd expect to get a random permutation of the items. Is there any other possible interpretation?

Comment: @celtschk taken together with the question about distributions it's rather confusing. A random permutation does not have anything to do with distributions.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: So you think all random permutations have to be uniformly distributed? Actually I think it makes a lot of sense to have an initial distribution and to update it using Bayes' rule each time a number is drawn (to account for the fact that we now know that the number cannot be drawn again). For example, if the initial distribution is $p(1)=1/2, p(2)=p(3)=1/4$, and you draw all three numbers, then the probabilities of the different permutations are $p(123)=p(132)=1/4, p(213)=p(312)=1/6, p(231)=p(321)=1/12$.

Comment: This may be semantics, but I believe you're talking about the distribution of permutations and not about the distribution of numbers drawn from a random permutation.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: The $p(1)$ to $p(3)$ definitely define a distribution for the single numbers 1 to 3. Of course a distribution on the numbers implies a distribution on the permutations. For the distribution I've given ($1/2,1/4,1/4$), I've also written down the resulting probability distribution for the permutations. However I did start from a single number probability distribution (otherwise Bayes' rule wouldn't make sense because after you've drawn a complete permutation, you cannot draw any additional numbers, so you cannot update your probability distribution anyway).

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain discrete uniform or normally distributed numbers from [random.org](http://www.random.org/clients/), which [allows you to generate 200k bits/day](http://www.random.org/quota/).

```
Import["http://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=1024&format=f", "Binary"]
```

Comment: That looks like a handy import statement, what format and range do you get ?

Comment: It looks to be a uniform distribution between 0 and 255. The format is just a list of 1024 integers.

Comment: @jVincent What result did you get? Executing the `Import` I got a list of 83 integers between 32 and 121. Executing it again .. I got exactly the same list of 83 numbers, which look suspiciously ASCII in range. Further investigation reveals that the bytes translate to ..."You have used your quota of random bits for today.  See the quota page for details." Mystery solved :)

Comment: Actually, that's a terrible interface for reporting exhausted quota when asking for binary data because it means if you are not careful, your code will silently use non-random values. Instead they should have used an HTTP error (maybe `412 Precondition Failed`; if you can extend your quota by paying — I didn't check that — also `402 Payment Required` might be reasonable).

Comment: OK, I now looked at the documentation of the site, and according to their documentation, they indeed *do* return an error status code (503). That means, the problem is with Mathematica, for ignoring the error.

Answer (score 2):

If you need high quality non-pseudo random numbers one solution is to use  hardware based devices.

One such device can be found here:
[Quantum Random Number Generator](http://www.idquantique.com/true-random-number-generator/products-overview.html)

It's application with Mathematica can be found here:
[Mathematica QRNG](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465511002748)

Available parametric distributions in Mathematica can be found here:
[MMA Distributions](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/parametric-probability-distributions/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RandomSample` to ensure non-repeating random selection.  The example below produces a flat distribution of unique values which you could reduce to the distribution you require.  Accuracy is increased by sampling from a larger initial population.

```
a = RandomSample[Union[RandomInteger[10^7, 10^6]], 10^4];
Histogram[a]
If[Union[a] == Sort[a], "No repeated values", "Repeated values"]
```

[image]